# .NET Core 2.0 Is the below code thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Here's my code and I have doubt on thread safe implementation. My questions are below

1. The return value from GetHtmlPageAsync is object. Is it thread safe? I will use this object and add into the collection and finally upload into database.
2. The main method logic is below (implementation in-progress). I have set of domains, I have list of 10000 domains in the collection, the idea is, I will put it in the queue and call the GetHtmlPageAsync to get the HTML of the page. Based on the HTML, I will get the necessary hyperlinks. Once I get the hyper links, I will check certain word is available in the link. If the word is available in the link, I will call the same method GetHTMLPageAsync to get the HTML of that page. So the same thread may call the GetHtmlPageAsync to process another link. I am trying to reuse the same method for multiple calls in thread safe way. Please help.

**@edit1** . I have added the main method. Instead of Queue. I have used ForEach

```
public static async Task<int> ProcessDomainAsync(List<string> domains)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(domains, async (currentDomain) =>
        {
            var domainBody = await GetHtmlPageAsync(currentDomain);
            var language = string.Empty;
            var country = string.Empty;
            var createdOn = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local);
            var updatedOn = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local);
            var machine = Environment.MachineName;
            var message = "[" + domainBody.ErrorCode + "] - " + domainBody.ErrorMessage;
            var active = false;
            var stage = "End";
            var url = currentDomain;
            if (domainBody.ErrorCode == 0)
            {
                var html = domainBody.Body;
                language = Common.GetLanguageIdentification(html);
                country = Common.GetCountryIdentification(currentDomain);
                message = string.Empty;
                active = true;
                stage = "Stage1";
                var hyperLinks = Common.GetAllAHrefTags(html);
                //Process Hyper Links
            }
            _domainList.Add(new Domain
            {
                Url = url,
                Language = language,
                Country = country,
                MachineName = machine,
                Message = message,
                Active = active,
                Stage = stage,
                CreatedOn = createdOn,
                UpdatedOn = updatedOn
            });
            domainCount++;
        });
        return domainCount;
    }
public class DomainBody
{
    public string Body;
    public string ErrorMessage;
    public int ErrorCode;
}

 public static class DomainProcessing    {

    static async Task<DomainBody> GetHtmlPageAsync(string url)
    {
        #region Initialize Proxy 
        var sessionId = new Random().Next().ToString();
        var proxy = new WebProxy(Constant.ProxyUrl, Constant.ProxyPort);
        var login = Constant.ProxyUserName + "-session-" + sessionId;
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login,Constant.ProxyPassword);
        #endregion

        #region Initialize Variables
        var user_agent = Common.GenerateRandomUserAgent();
        var body = string.Empty;
        var errorCode = 0;
        var errorMessage = string.Empty;
        #endregion

        try
        {
            #region Format URL with Http Protocol

            var domainSB = new StringBuilder();
            domainSB.Append("http://");
            domainSB.Append(url);

            #endregion

            #region Process Domain

            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            request.Proxy = proxy;
            request.UserAgent = user_agent;
            request.Timeout = Constant.TimeOut;

            using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(true))
            using (var content = new MemoryStream())
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                await responseStream.CopyToAsync(content);
                var bodyArray = content.ToArray();
                body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyArray, 0, bodyArray.Length);
            }

            errorCode = 0;
            errorMessage = string.Empty;

            #endregion 
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            body = string.Empty;
            errorCode = ex.InnerException.HResult;
            errorMessage = ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            body = string.Empty;
            errorCode = ex.HResult;
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
        }

        var domainBody = new DomainBody
        {
            Body = body,
            ErrorCode = errorCode,
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage
        };

        return domainBody;
    }
}enter code here
```

Comment: Is it something wrong in way of asking question. Not sure. Why it is down voted and down voter did not give any specific reason. This is my fourth or fifth question in stackoverflow. Not everyone may be a master in single day. Just my thoughts and no offense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, local variables should be thread safe (simply because they have no idea there even is another thread and other threads have no way to access them).

Anything that *can* be accessed by multiple threads should be looked at. `_domainList` for example. Make sure the `Add` method is thread-safe because you are calling it potentially in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I am using BlockingCollection. I thought BlockingCollection Add and Take is thread safe. Do I need to add lock and then add objects into BlockingCollection.

Comment: A BlockingCollection should be fine.